# Does F# have its own string manipulation libraries?

Tags: dll, f#

**Does F# have its own string manipulation libraries?**

As I am attempting to learn F#, I find myself using the existing System.string methods?

Should I be doing this?

**Code:**

```
open System

type PhoneNumber = 
    { CountryCode:int
      Number:string }

// b. Create a function formatPhone that accepts a PhoneNumber record and formats it to look like something like this: "+44 1234 456789"  
let formatPhone phoneNumber =

    let getLeadingCharacters (length:int) (text:string) =
        text.Substring(0, length)

    let getLastCharacters (length:int) (text:string) =
        text.Substring(text.Length - length, length)

    printf "+%i %s %s" phoneNumber.CountryCode 
                       (phoneNumber.Number |> getLeadingCharacters 4)
                       (phoneNumber.Number |> getLastCharacters 6)

formatPhone { CountryCode=44; Number="123456789" };;
```

**UPDATE**

**Updated function from:**

```
let formatPhone phoneNumber =

    let getLeadingCharacters (length:int) (text:string) =
        text.Substring(0, length)

    let getLastCharacters (length:int) (text:string) =
        text.Substring(text.Length - length, length)

    printf "+%i %s %s" phoneNumber.CountryCode 
                       (phoneNumber.Number |> getLeadingCharacters 4)
                       (phoneNumber.Number |> getLastCharacters 6)

formatPhone { CountryCode=44; Number="123456789" };;
```

**to:**

```
let formatPhone phoneNumber =

    printf "+%i %s %s" phoneNumber.CountryCode 
                       phoneNumber.Number.[0..3]
                       phoneNumber.Number.[4..8]

formatPhone { CountryCode=44; Number="123456789" };;
```

Comment: I create such small *anti-corruption functions* like `getLeadingCharacters` all the time. It strikes me as being perfectly normal.

Comment: Adopted from the term *anti-corruption layer* from [DDD](http://amzn.to/WBCwx7).

Comment: while yes it's true that you most likely use the provided string methods in this case I would use *ranges* (that now work with strings just fine) - for example `"Hello curel Wolrd".[6..10]` will give you `"cruel"` ;)

Comment: [_anti-corruption layer_](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/184472/49838) Nice to know.

Comment: Thanks Carsten, I updated my posted example.

Comment: @GuyCoder That's simply an ACL to the dwellers of DDD-CQRS-ES :)

Comment: @RubenBartelink I have no clue to what you just commented. Can you explain for those of us less fortunate.

Comment: @GuyCoder :) There's a GG https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dddcqrs which discusses DDD, event sourcing and CQRS. ACL is a core UL term there (I was reminded by this thread of (even having read the blue book at the time) wondering about this weird access control scheme people kept wanting to bring into the conversation). BTW The Evans book for me is in the top 10 books to read no matter who you are (its a tough enough read but some very useful stuff that informs day to day work even 12 years later)

Comment: @RubenBartelink :) I'll stick with provability first. I have been around so long that what's old is new. e.g. cloud computing is not new, see [IBM VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VM_(operating_system)) .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, F# does not have a specific [String library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) that duplicates the .NET library. It does have a [string module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353758.aspx) with extra string functions.

Yes, use the .NET functions.

The fact that F# can make use of all of the .NET library is one of it's strongest features. It does seem odd at first to mix functions using curried parameters with functions from .NET using tuple parameters.

That is why in NuGet you will see packages that also have the FSharp extension. e.g. [MathNet Numerics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics/) and [MathNet Numerics FSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathNet.Numerics.FSharp/). These are wrapper functions that allow for idiomatic F# use of the .NET library.

In checking the F# documentation for [Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/strings) there is one section noting the [String class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/strings#string-class) and another section noting [String module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/strings#string-module).

---

Part of original answer that is no longer correct.

When looking for functions and methods for use with F# I often use this trick.
To search .NET use `class` as a keyword and to search for F# specific code use `module` as keyword.

For example:

Google: `MSDN string class`
First item: [String Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx)

Google: `MSDN string module`
First item: [Core.String Module (F#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353758.aspx) (This is now a 404) but it is also a valid link for F# Language Reference for [String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/strings). Something is amiss.

Comment: You're a wealth of Knowledge. How can I follow you? For example, YouTube, Blogs, Podcasts, etc...

Comment: I get most of my knowledge by following the [F# top answers](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/f%23/topusers) and reading most of the new questions here. I do read lots of research papers at [CiteSeer](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/index) and write lots and lots of code. I have spent the last few months on just the basics of Neural Networks and sticking with problems, even if they take a week or more to resolve. I recently learned that one of the best ways to debug neural networks is with visual images and not looking at the values of all the weights and biases.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you are using open source libraries like FAKE for scripting,
you can reuse it's StringHelper module.

FAKE contains a StringHelper module https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/StringHelper.fs

Comment: isn't this just a comment posted as an answer?